# Date pattern with Spring MVC form tags

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, datetime-format, spring-form

I have a entity class and it has java.util.Date type property. And when I pass "path" param to my input as defult it shows me like this :

[image]

But I want to change pattern of it. Also it must display existing Date value of selected owner object.

I tried to use fmt:formatDate but it doesnt work :/

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><spring:message code="label.name" /><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                           <fmt:formatDate value="${owner.installDate}" var="installDate" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                           <form:input type="date" path="installDate"  value="${installDate}" class="form-control" placeholder="Yuklenme tarixini yazin....." required="true" />
                           <form:errors path="installDate" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you have following covered in your code.

1. The tag library is added in your jsp
2. Also make sure `owner.installDate` returns java.util.Date not String
3. Add `type="date"`to your code

   <fmt:formatDate value="${owner.installDate}" var="installDate" type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
4. Parse the date string first to java.util.Date as below

<fmt:parseDate value="${owner.installDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" var="myDate"/>

<fmt:formatDate value="${myDate}" var="installDate" type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Yeah have add fmt library to my jsp. But you are right it might be return string from database. Cause when I want to create new owner it show this error : Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date]

Comment: in that case you should parse the date string as updated in my answer

Comment: endless thanks to you my brother . I solved  problem with adding @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") annotation to my Date type property. But still in update page it doesnt display existing value .Even though i use <fmt:formatDate ,  input pattern still is same "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: With @DateTimeFormat you probabily solve only for ajax requests. If you change jsp, you must use another bean:
MyBean mb = new MyBean();//your bean with data
VBean vb = mapMyBeanToVBean(mb);
model.addAttribute("owner", vBean);

// structure of VBean could be the same of MyBean with String values